# Building new Xamarin.iOS project doesn't work without C++

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

> Error "Xamarin could not find
>   microsoft.visualc.cppclassifierprovider".

I use the latest VS preview with xamarin and c# installed.

Do I need to check C++ in the installer? Then why isn't it a required installation dependency? If it's not required I wouldn't like it to take GBs on my SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by uninstalling GLSL extension from VS installer.